# Why does this SQLite transaction with prepared statements not work?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, transactions, insert

I'm trying to combine an SQLite transaction and prepared statement to get the best insert speed for thousands of records. However, all the inserted lines are empty.

Printing the variables before inserting shows that they have the correct data and there are no errors.

```
$db->beginTransaction();
$insert_stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (:id, :value2, :value3, :value4)");
$insert_stmt->bindValue(":id", $id);
$insert_stmt->bindValue(":value2", $value2);
$insert_stmt->bindValue(":value3", $value3);
$insert_stmt->bindValue(":value4", $value4);

foreach ($records as $record)
{
  $id = $record["id"];
  $value2 = $record["value2"];
  $value3 = $record["value3"];
  $value4 = $record["value4"];
  $insert_stmt->execute();
  print_r($db->errorInfo()); // print errors
}

$db->commit();
```

1. What's wrong with the code?
2. How can I get better output? Printing the prepared statements before executing for example, to see if there's something wrong with it.

Comment: Is `table` is your real table name or it just an example?? If its real the use inside `backtick` because its a reserved keyword in mysql

Comment: Following the previous comment, is `value2` a type for `:value2`?

Comment: "table" is not the real table name. I added backticks anyway. value2, I missed the ":" while sanitizing the data. Corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the `bindValue` calls into your loop.

The values get copied into the statement when you execute `bindValue`. Whatever happens to the variable you used to do that afterwards does not matter.

Comment: So this answer is wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12725863 Edit: Just tried it and you're right, it works when I do the binding inside the loop. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm. I don't know enough about PHP to answer that. You may want to leave a comment on the other answer. Maybe we are missing something.